# Remove last part of dynamic URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Can any one please help with this : 
i am trying to redirect this :
https://www.example.com/site/members/user-id/page/page-id/?user_filter=points
to this 
https://www.example.com/site/members/user-id/

please note that **/user-id/** & **/page-d/** are numbers that changes in every link.

I tried searching online and tried to come up with some thing but yet no success

Here what i tried so far

```
RewriteRule ^site/members/[0-9]{4}/page/$ https://www.example.com/site/members/[0-9]{4}/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

and this approach:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^site/members/([0-9]{4}+)$/pages/ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule (.*) /site/members/1$ [L,R=301]
```

Would Appreciate Any Help On that 
Thanks

Comment: Your first attempt 


     `RewriteRule ^site/members/[0-9]{4}/page/$ https://www.example.com/site/members/[0-9]{4}/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]`


failed because you are using regular expressions in the RewriteRule's destination. You can only use a plain text uri string or backreferences in the rewrite destination.


And in the second attempt you are almost there , `%{REQUEST_URI}` string starts with a leading slash ,so your condition pattern should be  `^/site/members/([0-9]{4}+)$/pages/ [NC,OR]`

Comment: Thank you @starkeen for your quick reply. i tried the following:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/members/([0-9]{4}+)$/page/ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule (.*) /site/members/1$ [L,R=301]`

but unfortunately it redirect the link to 'https://www.example.com/site/members/?user_filter=points' so the result is doesn't show the **user-id** in the redirected link and keeps `?user_filter=points` and the opposite should happen

Comment: Clear your browser cache and then test the following :


`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/members/([0-9]+)$/pages/ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule (.*) /site/members/%1? [L,R=301]`

Comment: @starkeen, thank you for your help and support.

Adding this is redirecting the links to :
https:///www.example.com/site/members/
and its is not adding the */user-id/* to the output
the output should be : 
https:///www.example.com/site/members/user-id/

Comment: There was a typo in the rule I posted in comment. I just noticed a `$` (added by mistake) in the condition pattern . I have posted an answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/members/([0-9]+)/pages/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /site/members/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.